# In Microsoft Access how do you delete all values in a single column without deleting the entire field.

Tags: microsoft-access

Is it possible to delete all of a column's data in access without deleting the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a query. Here's the SQL, substitute in the actual values:

```
Update [Table Name] Set [Field Name] = null
```

Comment: Or you can go into the interactive table data editor and just highlight all the rows and hit delete; that should set them to null (I think) or their default value if nulls aren't allowed.

Comment: Dunno why I didn't think of that, I've become too reliant on the GUI lately.

Comment: @allquixotic FYI: Doing that with a table actually asks if you want to delete the fields (which means remove them from the table all together). Doing the same thing in a query just has no affect.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the column and hit option H to replace data. Put and asterisk in the first box and leave the second box blank. Simplest way to do it.

Comment: It's a little more than what user348469 said, for example you have to choose current field for the "Look in" parameter but his answer definitely helped me as I needed to replace info in filtered Datasheet view

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy another column with the same number of records where each field in that column has no value....then just select, copy, paste...done....

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler: right click on the column header in access, select copy.  Now go to excel and paste into a excel column.  Now hit the delete key, then copy that.  Go back to access right click column header and paste.  Done.

Note: When selecting what to copy in excel may want to exclude column header or may get extra blank record.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the field in table view
2. Open Find and Replace

   Find What: *

   Look In: Current Field
3. Replace all

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the table's Design View and delete the column in question. Then add a new field with the same name as the column you just deleted.

This is the fastest option, particularly if you're dealing with a large table with many millions of rows, because the other listed options will take several minutes while Access is "thinking through" your copy/paste or find/replace criteria.  This method is basically instantaneous.